# React update input value on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component with an input field.

I want to update the value of the input field when a button is clicked, I can confirm that the value changes when I inspect element but it doesn't display in the input field. Below is a sample code to just to give an idea.

```
class InputField {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
 }
 state = {
  userInput: ''
 }
}

onClick = () => {
 this.setState({
  userInput: 'Test'
 })
}


render() {
 return ( <input value={this.state.userInput} name="sampleInput" />
  <button onClick={this.onClick}> Click me </button>  
 )
}
```

Comment: so many syntax error!!

Comment: @saurssaurav it's just an example to illustrate what he's trying to achieve

Comment: You have a wrong "} ".

Comment: It's just a sample code.

Answer (score 3):

### Fix syntax

your code is ok, just little order.

I add the whole component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class InputField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  state = {
    userInput: ''
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: 'Test'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.userInput} name="sampleInput" />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default InputField;
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what the actual issue was. Just the extra `}` after `state =` and the missing `<div>` in the return it seems.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to implement this as a functional component via [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). You could for instance use the [state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to store and render the `userInput` data as shown below:

```
import React from "react";

/* Declare functional InputField component */
function InputField () {

  /* Define local state hook to store the "user input" data */
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = React.useState("");

  const onClick = (e) => {
      /* Prevent button click's default behavior */
      e.preventDefault();
      /* Call the state's "setter" method to update "userInput" state */
      setUserInput('Test')
  }

   /* Render both input and button in a <> fragment */    
   return (<>
     <input value={this.state.userInput} name="sampleInput"/>
     <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>  
   </>)
}
```

To use this component, simply render it as:

```
<InputField />
```

Answer (score 1):

I just removed syntax error in your example and it worked for me.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class InputField extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            userInput: ''
        }
    }

    onClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            userInput: 'Test'
        })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input value={this.state.userInput} name="sampleInput"/>
                <button
                    onClick = {this.onClick} 
                >
                    Click me
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fix your syntax errors and it run no any error

```
class InputField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
         userInput: '',
     };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      userInput: 'Test',
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.state.userInput} name="sampleInput" />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `defaultValue` attribute**

```
const [name, setName] = useState("")

<input defaultValue={name} placeholder='Enter Name' onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />

<button onClick={()=>setName("Umesh Bedi")}>Add Name</button>
```

I hope, It will help someone in functional component.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

export default class InputField extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            userInput: ''
        }
    }

    onClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            userInput: 'Test'
        })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input value={this.state.userInput} name="sampleInput"/>
                <button
                    onClick = {this.onClick} 
                >
                    Click me
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see no difference between this code and that in another answer. Either highlight the difference(s) or delete the post.