# How to change state and display the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, setstate, react-state

How to change the value in the state of a component using a button. And how to display the new value instead of old When ever I click the button.
For example here I have a component of Appp :-

```
class Appp extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      name : "super man"
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleSubmit(){
    this.setState(state => ({
      name : document.getElementById('id').value
    }))

  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>

      <form>
        <span>Name : </span>
      <input type={"text"} id={"id"}/>
      <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Click Me</button>

      </form>
      <div>
        {this.state.name}
      </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want the div containing the `this.state.name` to change value whenever I click the button.

I created a button which on clicking it will call the `handleSubmit()` function which change the value of name in the state with the value inside the input tag.
Then the second div tag will show then value in the name.
But whenever I click the button it doesn't displaying the current value of name in the div tag.
I was expecting the div to show the value given in the input field(Changing the `state.name` with the value inside the input feild tooo).

Thank you :)

Comment: see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57990563/20261328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two events `onChange` = `handleChangeName` and `value` = `name` for `input tag`.

- `onChange` will be trigger when you typo and then the component re-render by `setName`.
- `value` always updates by `name` state.

I reworked your component by `Function Component`:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("super man");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    // Prevent the default behavior of "form tag" when pressed "Click me" (Don't reload page)
    e.preventDefault();

    // You can see input's value when pressed "Click me" in `console.log`
    console.log(name);
  };

  const handleChangeName = (e) => {
    setName(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <span>Name : </span>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChangeName} value={name} />
        <button type="submit">Click Me</button>
      </form>
      <p>
        Input's value entered: <b>{name}</b>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

You can refer at this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-waterfall-4qcn0y?file=/src/App.js